# password_verify() function warned as undefined constant

Tags: php, hashcode

I recently used a format for my login that stored the password in the database using `$password = md5(password_1)` *full code below...*

Then changed that to `$password = (password_hash($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` *full code below....*

it successfully saved a hashed password in my database like:`$2y$10$.FTJmF/47NbmQMU3nZGTZeKAHYZ8TBm8X2Jc.TLbAIK...`

Now verifying the password is where something is going wrong,
The original code was  `$password = md5($password_1)` which would successfully log me in with the md5 storing in the first code.
 I changed that to `$password = password_verify($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFUALT);`

but thats giving me this error.

[image]

Ive tried `$hash = password_verify($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );`
but its giving me the same error,

```
 <?php
```

session_start();

```
// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM loginsystem WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
  //Hashing the password
  $password = password_hash($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO loginsystem (username, email, password) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: home.php');
  }
}

// ... 
// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0)  $password = password_verify($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM loginsystem WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}
```

?>

Comment: the function arguments for password_verify are wrong, use following: bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )

Comment: you can only verify the password _after_ you got the hash from the database.

Comment: I thought thats what this function was doing, was getting it from the database. (new to php and web developing , etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apart from the typos there are two problems:

**1st**: [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) has different parameters: the typed password and the hashed password from database.

which leads us to the **second problem**:
You can only verify the password after you got the hash from the database.
So get that hash first (by querying for usename alone), than verify.

```
$query = "SELECT username, email, password FROM loginsystem WHERE username='$username'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        // password correct!
    } else {
        // nope
    }
} else {
    // wrong credentials
}
```

You should also change to a [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as this now could be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Voted up, solved the issue. Thank you for the clarification on the actual placement of the code.

Comment: You're welcome! ...but you didn't vote up. And if it solved your problem you can accept the answer!

Comment: i have less than 15rep thats probably why it wont show up.

Answer (score -1):

`PASSWORD_DEFUALT` is misspelled. It should be `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` as in the example below:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

[...]

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // Password matches
}
```

The first parameter of `password_verify` is the user-entered password. The second parameter is the stored hash generated by `password_hash`.

Comment: that took away the undefined constant error but the "Undefined variable: password_1 " error is still showing up.
Thank you btw.

Comment: i had fixed that whenever i fixed your correction and still the same error

Comment: any luck fnding the error? the message went away but im getting the incorrect password everytime.

Comment: The first parameter to `password_verify` is the password typed in by the user. The second parameter is the hash stored in the database (that was generated by `password_hash`).

Comment: which would be $password="$password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT"); if so thats giving me correct me if im wrong, but that ends up giving me an undefined variable error